# How to make file upload facultative with Deform and Colander?

Tags: python, pyramid, deform, colander

I would like to render a form containing a sequence of files, representing different images of a product. Providing files should be facultative, so the form should validate even in the absence of files. How can I do this ?

Here is the colander schema I use:

```
    import colander
    import deform
    from deform import Form
    from deform import ValidationFailure
    from deform.interfaces import FileUploadTempStore 


    tmpstore = FileUploadTempStore()

    class Image(colander.Schema):
        image = colander.SchemaNode(
            deform.FileData(),
            widget=deform.widget.FileUploadWidget(tmpstore)
            ) 

    class Images(colander.SequenceSchema):
        images = Image()

    class ProductSchema(colander.Schema):
        completename = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(), title="Complete Name")

        description = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(), 
                                 widget = deform.widget.TextAreaWidget())

        images = Images()


    schema = ProductSchema()
    form = Form(schema, buttons=("submit", ))
```

I tried to add a 'missing' argument like:

```
image = colander.SchemaNode(
        deform.FileData(),
        missing = ???
        widget=deform.widget.FileUploadWidget(tmpstore)
        )
```

I think I get something functional when

```
missing={'filename': None, 'uid':None}
```

But I'm really not sure it's the correct way to do it...

Thanks !

Comment: Better ask on the Pylons list

Comment: @Sentinel - Why *better*? This is a totally good question for SO, as those on Django and other framework... What was the point you were trying to do? (Honest question, I'm just trying to understand the logic)

Comment: @mac: if it's a good question, why don't you upvote it ? ;-)

Comment: @ascobol - +1 because you asked for it, but since I don't know anything about pylons, it's difficult for me to tell if you did your research well before posting the question (maybe there are a trillions other identical questions phrased differently on SO?).

Comment: @Sentinel: Mailing lists suck. They are often much slower than sites like SO, you often have to sign up first (and then receive mails about crap you don't care about), ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try "missing = colander.null".